# How to insert "edit" and "delete" button dynamically in the table using javascript and populates the data in the form again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made one html5 form. I use the array of objects in JavaScript. I stored the user input in the array. But I failed in some functionality.

1. I want to insert the  "edit" and "delete"  button in the table dynamically. So that when the user click on the edit button, the data populates in above html form, edit it and submit the updated data in same row.
2. I want to insert delete button, so that on click of "delete" button, same row data should be deleted. That entry should also delete from the array.
3. I want to generate "ID" dynamically for each row so that after deleting any record that "Id" will update.

Can you please give me the solution? How can I generate these functionalities? What is the extra code should I add in the JavaScript?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#button').click(function() {
    if ($('#firstName').val() == '') {
      $('#error').html('Please fill the FirstName details.');
      $('#error').css('color', 'red');
    } else if ($('#lastName').val() == '') {
      $('#error').html('Please fill the LastName details.');
      $('#error').css('color', 'red');
    } else if ($('#DOB').val() == '') {
      $('#error').html('Please fill  the date of birth details.');
      $('#error').css('color', 'red');
    } else if ($('#image').val() == '') {
      $('#error').html('Please upload the image');
      $('#error').css('color', 'red');
    } else {

      $('#error').html('');


      var firstname = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
      var lastname = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
      var dob = document.getElementById('DOB').value;
      var image = document.getElementById('image');
      var imgName = image.files[0].name;

      var id = 0;

      var table = {
        firstName: firstname,
        lastName: lastname,
        dob: dob,
        image: imgName
      };

      var tableContaint = [];

      tableContaint.push(table);

      for (var i = 0; i < tableContaint.length; i++) {
        $('#list tbody').prepend("<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + tableContaint[0].firstName + "</td><td>" + tableContaint[0].lastName + "</td><td>" + tableContaint[0].dob + "</td><td>" + tableContaint[0].image + "</td><td>" + "<input type='button' id='edit' value='edit' onclick ='ValidateEdit()'>&nbsp&nbsp<input type='button' id='delete' value='delete'/>" + "</td></tr>")
      }
      $('.form').val('');
    }
    $('.form').val('');
  });

});
```

```css
.form {
  display: inline;
  width: 20%;
  /* height: 34px; */
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#submit {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <center>
    <h1> Fill This Form </h1>
  </center>
  <p id='error' align="center">
    <form id='myForm' value='reset'>
      <div align="center" class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First-Name:- </label>
        <input type="text" class="form" id='firstName'>
      </div>

      <div align="center" class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last-Name:- </label>
        <input type="text" class="form" id="lastName">
      </div>

      <div align="center" class="form-group">
        <label for="DOB"> DATE OF BIRTH:-</label>
        <input type="date" class="form" id="DOB">
        <span><input type="text" class="form" disabled></span>
      </div>


      <div align="center" class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Your Image </label>
        <input type="file" class="form" id="image" style="display:inline">
      </div>


      <div id="submit">
        <input type="button" id="button" value="submit"></input>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Resulted Table</h2>

  <table id="list" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Date Of Birth</th>
        <th> Image </a>
        </th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The array should hold the id values and when a record is deleted, loop over the array from where the record was in javascript and renumber the entries and refresh only the numbers on the page. This would be cumbersome though.

Comment: Start by validating your HTML. There are some lose </a> and do not call anything"submit" since it is the name of a form method you may want to use

Comment: Then please show some effort. There are 3 questions - there is no code that shows what you tried

Comment: I dont have knowledge about javascript. But its a requirement sir. Just show me the js code ,which can perform these functionalities .

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your html and jquery. Line 43 : you start with `<tr>` but end with `</th>`(Line 49). You should end with `</tr>`. Line 50 : replace `<th></th>` to `<tbody></tbody>`. use `append()` instead of `prepend()` in your jquery(Line 41).
[Preview](https://jsfiddle.net/9wkpf976/)

Comment: I did the changes in html.....then how to use javascript to add these functionalities ?

Comment: You have used $('#list tbody').prepend() in for loop. Use $('#list tbody').append()

Comment: tr += '<td><button onclick="delete(' + tableContaint[i].id + ')">Delete</button></td>'   . I write this html code to perform functionality dynamically on the delete button. But it doesn't work?                                                                        I  write this below code to delete object from the array...But it is giving me error. can anyone give me the correct solution ?                                                       I

Comment: tr += <td><button onclick="delete(' + tableContaint[i].id + ')">Delete</button></td>  . I write this html code to onclick dynamically on the delete button. But it doesn't work?                                                                        }